# PyCharm debugger attaches to local process but doesn't pause

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I've got a long-running Python 3.5 process that has hung.  I followed https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/attaching-to-local-process.html to attach to the process.

I have successfully attached to the process

```
Attaching to a process with PID=4332
C:\Python35\python3.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd_attach_to_process\attach_pydevd.py" --port 13980 --pid 4332
Connected to pydev debugger (build 172.3317.103)
Attach finished successfully.
```

but when I press the PyCharm debugger pause button to examine the state nothing happens.